# Regex – Return first group match

Tags: regex

regex newbie here.

Say that I have the following string:

```
818y1873+130I have some text here09 124i10029102lsdgn2in3>31<
mkm1ikm12klni12m4j12??=?!=I"=and then some text heremsiJR310>39<0MK)==!)="!
```

What I would like to retrieve is the **31**.

So, putting my query in English terms: after the string `I have some text here` followed by any character, the first (double) digits you find that are/is encapsulated by ><, retrieve that group for me.

I've tried the following pattern: `r'I have some text here[\s\S\w\W\d\D]+>(\d{1,2})<'`, but it returns 39–the last occurence–see: https://regex101.com/r/cevLwj/1

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Short answer, you are missing that its currently greedy with the `+`. If you want the quick fix use `+?`. But maybe someone can come up with a better pattern.

Comment: Why are you using `[\s\S\w\W\d\D]`? `[\s\S]` means the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `>(\d{1,2})<` prepended by word characters `\w` and whitspaces `\s`.

Result: `[\w\s]+>(\d{1,2})<`

See working example: https://regex101.com/r/RUK9te/1

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
I have some text here[^>]+>(\d\{1,2\})<
```

(Very likely will need to be tweaked to suit your input, but based on the information you have provided, this should be good enough.)

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to work, however see Webber's answer. Thanks for your reply nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

```
^.*?>(\d\d?)<
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/jgi58x/1)

Comment: Hi Toto! Thanks for you reply. In this case, `I have some text here` is relevant to me.

Is there a way to apply this/start searching **after** a specific substring?

Comment: You reckon the below is usable?

`(?<=I have some text here.*?>(\d\d?)<`

It seems to give me the correct results, however generalisability is important to me.

Cheers

Comment: @KevinSiemons: Yes, of course, you can use `(?<=I have some text here.*?>)\d\d?(?=<)` but only if your regex flavor supports variable length lookbehind, if it doesn't, use: `I have some text here.*?>(\d\d?)<` and the digits you're searching is in group 1.

Comment: Read and understood. Much obliged!